# How can I select a UITableView item from the app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am listening for an APN that there is a new message in a conversation with a particular friend. W it is received, I want to select the second tab in my tab navigation and then select the conversation that is specified in the incoming payload. I got it working such that, assuming we have passed authentication and are shown the proper tab, but now I want to select the proper cell in the table and I don't see how to do that.

Additionally, I'd like to select a particular controller rather than hardcode the fact that this is tab 2 but I couldn't make that work either.

Here is the meat of it:

```
UITabBarController *tabViewController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
tabViewController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

and here is more context:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    DDLogDebug(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification got launch options: %@", launchOptions);

    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *message = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];

    NSNumber *fromUserId = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"from_user"];
    if (fromUserId) {
        DDLogDebug(@"Got message from friend id %@", fromUserId);
        [self showConversationWithfriendIdWhenPossible:fromUserId message:message];
    }
}

- (void)showConversationWithfriendIdWhenPossible: (NSNumber *)friendId message:(NSString *) message {
    FriendMatch *friend = [FriendMatch MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:friendId];

    DDLogDebug(@"Got friend %@", friend.firstName);

    if (message) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    if (![self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        self.showConversationWithfriendId = friendId;
        DDLogDebug(@"Not showing the conversation because the controller is %@", NSStringFromClass([self.window.rootViewController class]));
        return;
    }
    self.showConversationWithfriendId = nil;
    DDLogDebug(@"val: %@", (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController);
    UITabBarController *tabViewController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    tabViewController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should capitalize the first letter of each word in your class names, so `friendMatch` would become `FriendMatch`. This will allow you to easily make a distinction between instance variables and classes, and give you more sanity.

**Table row selection**

I'm assuming you have some list of friends somewhere--I'm calling it `friends`. This code selects the row, and scrolls the table to the selection, so that the selection appears in the middle of the displayed cells. This operation is also useful after sorting your table.

```
int numFriends = friends.count;
for (int i = 0; i < numFriends; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = friends[i];
    if (dict == matchedFriend)
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [_friendsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
        [_friendsTable selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:FALSE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

        break;
    }
}
```

**Tab selection**

For selecting a tab in your tab bar, I would use an approach that maps each tab bar item to some meaningful name, using a dictionary. This way, you can select a given tab, regardless of its position.

Comment: Point of clarification: You should capitalize the first letter of class NAMES, and the first letter of all other words in ALL names, in Cocoa. Your wording isn't clear. When you say "all words" readers are likely to think you mean all words.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer--the code in the question already uses good convention for instance variables,

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I get a handle on the _friendsTable in the context this being called - via didReceiveRemoteNotification? It is on the screen after the proper tab is selected. Should I be saving a reference to the UITableView or can I get there at runtime without having saved a reference to it since it is on screen?

Comment: You should probably keep your friends table private to the view controller that displays it. And, you need to make sure you initialize the friends array before the table is populated (or call reload on the table, at the end of some asynchronous process). So, you should probably call the initialization routine for the array in viewDidLoad of the view controller.

Comment: I can see that my row is now being selected (it is gray) but how can I make it do what happens when a user clicks on the row?

Comment: Do you want to initiate some action, in response to the click event? If so, you can implement the UITableViewDelegate method: tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.